# Python: passing instance variable to class method

Tags: python, python-2.7, xlsxwriter

I am using `xlsxwriter` and I have created a class where I have created a workbook. Then I have added 2 worksheets to it.
Now I have written a method that's writing data to one of the worksheets, but now I would like to use it on both worksheets. This is a simple example to explain the situation:

```
import xlsxwriter

class ExcelWorkbook():
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook(filename)
        self.ws1 = self.wb.add_worksheet('Num')
        self.ws1LineCount = 0
        self.ws2 = self.wb.add_worksheet('Result')
        self.ws2LineCount = 0

    def write_data(self, data, title):        
        self.ws1.write_row(self.ws1LineCount, 0, title)
        self.ws1LineCount += 1
        self.ws1.write_row(self.ws1LineCount, 0, data)
        self.ws1LineCount += 1

xlsxWorkbook = ExcelWorkbook('Test2.xlsx')
numArr = (0.000000520593523979187, 13.123456789, 1.789456, 0.002345, 0.00123, 1)
titleBar = ('Date', 'quantity', 'Average [m]', 'Standard Dev [m]', 'Test', 'Success')
xlsxWorkbook.write_data(numArr, titleBar)
```

Now I'd like to use the `write_data` method for both worksheets, so I thought I'd pass the worksheet as a parameter, but unfortunately it's not that simple, as I cannot pass the instance variable `self.ws1` or `self.ws2`.

So the question is: how can I do that?

I came up with a very nasty solution, like this:

```
def write_data(self, data, title, instance = 'ws1'):
    if instance == 'ws1':
        instance = self.ws1
        lineCounter = self.ws1LineCount
    elif instance == 'ws2':
        instance = self.ws2
        lineCounter = self.ws2LineCount

    instance.write_row(self.ws1LineCount, 0, title)
    lineCounter += 1
    instance.write_row(self.ws1LineCount, 0, data)
    lineCounter += 1
```

but honestly I don't like it. Is there a proper way to do it, or is it like a completely unreasonable thing?

Comment: hello, what about storing the excel sheet in a list. then you can iterate it to access each of them?

Comment: What do you mean that you cannot pass the instance variable? You should be able to with `xlsxWorkbook.write_data(data, title, xlsxWorkbook.ws1)`

Comment: @CarlosMermingas what is `xlsxWorkbook`? I have tried to pass `instance = self.ws1` as a keyword argument with default value, but it didn't work...

Comment: It's in your code: `xlsxWorkbook = ExcelWorkbook('Test2.xlsx')`. It's the instance of `ExcelWorkbook`

Comment: `self` is just a name that you pick. It is not a special word in Python. You cannot use `self` unless it is defined somewhere. You can use it in methods in a class because it is set as the first argument.

Comment: @CarlosMermingas yes, sorry. It works in your way, but what if I want to give it a default value?

Comment: @toti08 You can't access `self` in a default value, I'll update my answer to address this...

Comment: Yeah, exactly, I know that wouldn't work, that's why I haven't posted that code...but you guys actually gave me great hints!

Comment: @Aybars thanks for your comment, that was also another idea, but it would actually break a lot of already existing code, and I'd like to avoid it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the if block, better use `workbook.get_worksheet_by_name()` method

```
def write_data(self, data, title, ws = 'Num'):
    wsheet = self.wb.get_worksheet_by_name(ws)
    wsheet.write_row(self.ws1LineCount, 0, title)
    lineCounter += 1
    wsheet.write_row(self.ws1LineCount, 0, data)
    lineCounter += 1
```

EDIT: or you can use getattr() function, e.g.

```
def write_data(self, data, title, ws = 'ws1'):
    wsheet = getattr(self, ws, self.ws1))
    wsheet.write_row(self.ws1LineCount, 0, title)
    lineCounter += 1
    wsheet.write_row(self.ws1LineCount, 0, data)
    lineCounter += 1
```

Comment: @toti08, of course, if you still want to use property (e.g. 'ws1'), not actull worksheet name, you can use getattr() function https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr

Comment: Thanks! The first approach works perfectly, while the second should be used with `wsheet = getattr(self, 'ws1')`. But both are good approaches, thanks!

Comment: @toni08, the second one should be used as I show you.  `wsheet = getattr(self, ws, 'ws1'))`. This way you can use default value when you call the `write_data()` method and also, if you pass a attribute that does not exists (e.g. 'ws3') still fall back to the default value of 'ws1'

Comment: Weird, if I use it the way you suggest I get an error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write_row'` because I got back a string (`ws1`) and not a worksheet instance....maybe because I'm in Python2?

Comment: @toti08, sorry - my mistake. it should be `wsheet = getattr(self, ws, self.ws1))`. I will edit my answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import xlsxwriter

class ExcelWorkbook():
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook(filename)

        self.ws1 = self.wb.add_worksheet('Num')
        self.ws2 = self.wb.add_worksheet('Result')
        self._line_counts = defaultdict(int)

    def write_data(self, ws, data, title):
        self._write_row(ws, title)
        self._write_row(ws, data)

    def _write_row(self, ws, content):
        ws.write_row(self._line_counts[ws], 0, content)
        self._line_counts[ws] += 1

xlsxWorkbook = ExcelWorkbook('Test2.xlsx')
numArr = (0.000000520593523979187, 13.123456789, 1.789456, 0.002345, 0.00123, 1)
titleBar = ('Date', 'quantity', 'Average [m]', 'Standard Dev [m]', 'Test', 'Success')
xlsxWorkbook.write_data(xlsxWorkbook.ws1, numArr, titleBar)
xlsxWorkbook.write_data(xlsxWorkbook.ws2, numArr, titleBar)
```

By using `defaultdict`, you don't need to explicitly keep a line count variable for each worksheet. The `write_data` function accepts a new parameter `ws` so that you can set the worksheet that should be written to. Writing a row can be factored into a separate method to reduce code duplication.

Does this answer your question?

**Edit:**

a default value cannot access `self`, but you can work around this quite easily:

```
def write_data(self, data, title, ws=None):
        if ws is None:            
            ws = self.ws1
        self._write_row(ws, title)
        self._write_row(ws, data)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's a good idea. What if I want to give the `ws` parameter a default value? I'm asking this because I wouldn't want to break already existing software...

Comment: please see my edit. There are shorter solutions (e.g. `ws = ws or self.ws1`), but they might be too "magical" for most coders and have slightly different semantics

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should consider to have an extra class `ExcelWorksheet`, in order to put all logic related to them inside:

```
class ExcelWorksheet(object):
    def __init__(self, workbook, name):
        self.wb = workbook
        self.ws = self.wb.add_worksheet(name)
        self.wsLineCount = 0

    def write_data(self, data, title):        
        self.ws.write_row(self.wsLineCount, 0, title)
        self.wsLineCount += 1
        self.ws.write_row(self.wsLineCount, 0, data)
        self.wsLineCount += 1
```

This way, you can refactor your code to this:

```
class ExcelWorkbook(object):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook(filename)
        self.ws1 = ExcelWorksheet(self.wb, 'Num')
        self.ws2 = ExcelWorksheet(self.wb, 'Result')


xlsxWorkbook = ExcelWorkbook('Test2.xlsx')
numArr = (0.000000520593523979187, 13.123456789, 1.789456, 0.002345, 0.00123, 1)
titleBar = ('Date', 'quantity', 'Average [m]', 'Standard Dev [m]', 'Test', 'Success')
xlsxWorkbook.ws1.write_data(numArr, titleBar)
xlsxWorkbook.ws2.write_data(numArr, titleBar)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's also a good idea, I'll think whether this is feasible in my case...

Comment: Glad to help you. Please, remember to chose an answer if your problem was resolved.

Answer (score -1):

With vars(self), you can access any element of the object as a dictionnary.

Then vars(self)["ws1"] is like self.ws1 and vars(self)["ws2"] is like self.ws2

Then you just have to pass a key argument "ws1" or "ws2" in write_data.

```
def write_data(self, data, title, key='ws1'):
    instance = vars(self)[key]
    lineCounter = vars(self)[key+"LineCount"]

    instance.write_row(lineCounter , 0, title)
    lineCounter += 1
    instance.write_row(lineCounter , 0, data)
    lineCounter += 1
```

Comment: While this should work, it's easy to break by providing a wrong `key` and IDE's are most likely not able to point that out using static analysis.

Comment: In fact like any basic function, a wrong arg does not work. But if you prefer your solution with a pseudo-static method asking as argument the reference to its own attribut... I wonder the interest of OOP when I see that.